# SQL age group and unique number

Tags: mysql, sql

How  i can write a script using a temporary table with the following fields: NAME, SURNAME, AGE, OS_NAME. From the result of the temporary table, remove all clients whose age is less than 15 years. As a result, display the phone's OS and the number of people who have this OS.

table name-  "AGE_GROUPS"

```
+-----------------------------------+
|NAME   | SURNAME  |AGE |OS_NAME    |
+-----------------------------------+
|Ivan   | Dulin    | 14 | Android8.1|
|-----------------------------------|
|Sasha  | Hlo      | 13 | WP        |
|-----------------------------------|
|Andrey | Zac      | 16 | IOS       |
|-----------------------------------|
|Carld  | Marks    | 17 |WP         |
|-----------------------------------|
|Dan    | Smiz     | 15 | IOS       |
|-----------------------------------|
|Ivan   | Meisa    | 12 | Android8.1|
|-----------------------------------|
|Pasha  | Las      | 4  | IOS       |
|-----------------------------------|
|Stas   | Istomin  | 25 | Android8.1|
|-----------------------------------|
|Chuan  | Zen      | 55 | WP        |
|-----------------------------------|
|Marina | Buzinovna|30  |IOS        |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I can't figure out what will happen after SELECT for NAME, SURNAME, AGE, OS_NAME where age> = 15
 no time to learn "group by"
my boss scolds me badly :(

Comment: Homework, and you expect us to do it for you?!? If we did, you wouldn't learn much.

Comment: Show us expected result, what you've tried etc: 'https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex

Comment: 1 - is a :SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN age_c < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Under 18],
        SUM(CASE WHEN age_c BETWEEN 18 AND 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [18-24],
        SUM(CASE WHEN age_c BETWEEN 25 AND 34 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [25-34]
 FROM contacts

Comment: but i dont know how me done a 2  :((((

Comment: Do it in two steps. Start with the SELECT for NAME, SURNAME, AGE, OS_NAME where age >= 15. Then do the GROUP BY on the result.

Comment: but i dont know how, i have a 1 hour, and if i cant done 2 quest I'll be fired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for thr first  you could use case when  ..and group by

```
select  case when  age between  1 and 12 then '1-12 children' 
             when  age between  13 and 18 then '13-18 - adolescents' 
             when  age between  19 and 23 then '19-23 - students' 
             when  age between  24 and 50 then '24-50 - adults'    
             else   '51+ - pensioners'   
        end   Group_by_age ,
        count(*)
from  my_table  
group by  Group_by_ag
```

Comment: @ПашаПетров change a question after a valid answer if not fair  .. you should restore the original question  ..  and eventually  or post a new question or  add the new info

Answer (score 0):

The question as is very different from the original question but if you do want 'display the phone's OS and the number of people who have this OS' then

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(NAME varchar(20), SURNAME varchar(20),AGE int,OS_NAME varchar(20));
insert into t values
('Ivan'  , 'Dulin'  ,14 , 'Android8.1'),
('Sasha' , 'Hlo'    ,13 , 'WP'),
('Andrey' , 'Zac'   ,16 , 'IOS'),
('Carld' , 'Marks'  ,17 , 'WP'),
('Dan' , 'Smiz'     ,15 , 'IOS'),
('Ivan' , 'Meisa'   ,12 , 'Android8.1'),
('Pasha' , 'Las'    ,4  , 'IOS'),
('Stas' , 'Istomin' ,25 , 'Android8.1'),
('Chuan' , 'Zen'    ,55 , 'WP'),
('Marina' , 'Buzinovna',  30 ,'IOS');

select os_name, count(*)
from t
where age > 15
group by os_name;

+------------+----------+
| os_name    | count(*) |
+------------+----------+
| Android8.1 |        1 |
| IOS        |        2 |
| WP         |        2 |
+------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```